# Using datasource defined in blueprint in java to access oracle db

Tags: java, oracle, database-connection, apache-camel, datasource

Below is my datasource

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="URL" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@${host}:${port}:${dbname}"/>
    <property name="user" value="${user}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${pass}"/>
</bean>
<service ref="dataSource" interface="javax.sql.DataSource">
    <service-properties>
        <entry key="osgi.jndi.service.name" value="jdbc/oracleds"/>
        <entry key="datasource.name" value="OracleDS"/> 
    </service-properties>
</service>
<bean id="LogToOracleDB" class="com.beans.LogToOracleDB">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

I want to use it in some bean file called `LogToOracleDB`

```
public class LogToOracleDB {
protected static DataSource dataSource;

public void test(Exchange exchange) throws SQLException {
      Connection con = dataSource.getConnection();
      Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
      ...............
}
```

Im getting null pointer exception while getting connection from `datasource` since its null. Can someone help me out lookingup datasource??

Comment: Why is your DataSource property static? If its a bean instance, you should work on that instance and don't need static variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dataSource = (DataSource)context.lookup(JNDIname);
```

You have to use like this,otherwise create a comboPool and try to look from that